# Do contradicting BTRFS subvolid's not cause trouble?

Tags: fstab, btrfs

I've been following a set of steps very similar to the ones mentioned on [the ArchWiki installation guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide).

I've recently started playing around with BTRFS snapshots, particularly of the `/` subvolume.

During installation, my mount command looks something like this:

```
mount -o noatime,nodiratime,compress=lzo,space_cache,subvol=@ /dev/sda3 /mnt
```

(considering `/dev/sda3` is the BTRFS partition containing all my system subvolumes).

`genfstab` produces an `/etc/fstab` in the below fashion:

```
# /dev/sda3
UUID=<long-uuid>    /    btrfs    rw,noatime,nodiratime,compress=lzo,space_cache,subvolid=256,subvol=/@,subvol=@  0  0
```

As you can see in the above snippet, it automatically adds the parameter for `subvolid` and also one more for a repeat `subvol` (which I don't care at this point).

The confusing part begins when I restore to a previous snapshot with commands like:

```
mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
mv /mnt/@ /mnt/<some-random-name>
mn /mnt/<an_old_snapshot_name> /mnt/@
```

it leaves the `/etc/fstab` file intact, which is OK in a sense if you consider that rather than changing the file, I renamed my subvolumes in a way that the same name now refers to a different subvolume, but what I'm confused about is the old `subvolid`, which even though remains unchanged, let's the right subvolume being mounted.

*To summarize:* does a different `subvolid` and `subvol` references not cause any issue while mounting volumes?

**PS**: I apologize for such a lengthy question and apparently also for a noob question, but couldn't find an answer by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [this comment on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/m2fxs4/do_contradicting_btrfs_subvolids_not_cause_trouble/gqj6mad), `subvolid` can be safely removed to make the references consistent.